# Edit Mode for list not showing Minus icons or allowing Swipe gestures

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm currently using Xcode 15 beta 4 and I'm experiencing difficulty in enabling the edit mode for a specific list. Despite my attempts, I haven't been successful in resolving the issue. I'm reaching out for assistance, as I'm unsure of the reason behind this problem.

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct Questionnaire: View {
    @State private var InfoTitle = ""
    @State private var Username = ""
    @State private var Password = ""
    @State private var DueDate = Date()
    @State private var Notes = ""
    @State private var Limit = 0
    
    //custom info stuff
    @State private var customInfo: [StringDictData] = []
    @State private var test = ""
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.active

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Information")) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
     
                    Text("Select an Info Image")
                }
                
                TextField("Info Title", text: $InfoTitle)
                
                DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $DueDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            }

            
            Section(header: Text("Login Information")) {
                TextField("Username", text: $Username)
                SecureField("Password", text:$Password)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Extra Information")) {
                TextField("Notes", text: $Notes)
            }
            
            Section() {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Custom Information")
                    Divider()
                    
                    List {
                        ForEach($customInfo, id: \.self) { $item in
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    TextField("Info Title", text: $item.key)
                                    
                                    TextField("Info Field", text: $item.value)
                                }
                                Divider()
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete { indexSet in
                            customInfo.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                        }
                    }
                    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        customInfo.append(StringDictData(key: "", value: ""))
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                            Text("Add Custom Info")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Questionnaire()
}
```

Unrelated to that, I've noticed another issue. No matter where I click, if it's not in the text field it seems to run the same thing the "Add Custom Info" button does.

I've tried using @Environment, put it in the for loop instead of the list, put it in a navigation view, used an EditButton(), with no luck.